# A Puzzle That Asks Why There's A Dryer in my Search Engine

Tags: riddle, word, rhyme

The bag is not transmogrified.
A hookah with some fizz inside.
The snake, the bite. The words of pride.

Comment: How the hell do you come up with such a brilliant riddle?

Comment: @infinitezero I thought of calling it “The Greatest Riddle in the History of Puzzle Making” but it sorta gives away the answer.

Comment: Well played....

Answer (score 52, accepted):

I think this is

> Boasting

The bag is not transmogrified.

> Boasting is 'bag is not' anagrammed

A hookah with some fizz inside.

> Bong, a hookah, including Asti which is a sparkling Italian white wine.

The snake, the bite. The words of pride.

> Boa (snake) + sting (bite). Boasting as speaking proudly.

A Puzzle That Asks Why There's A Dryer in my Search Engine

> An oast is a kiln for drying hops, inside Bing.

Comment: Just like old times! Congrats!

Comment: @Hugh Meyers, it's always a pleasure to see questions from you!